# Validator allowing color transitions

Tags: css, validation, amp-html

I'm using the validator (https://validator.ampproject.org/) to convert my page's invalid css to AMP friendly, according to the website (https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages) transition is limited to only opacity and transform.  Yet I have color animations all over the css, the validator doesn't seem to care about them.

Is the validator incorrect or outdated?  Has anyone else run into this? Perhaps AMP allows color transitions now? Thanks!

Ex snippet from my code:

```
  <style amp-custom>
    a {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #1274b8;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: color .25s ease-out, background-color .25s ease-out; //this is valid and passing
    }

    a:hover {
        color: purple;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: can post your code or any link to test.

Comment: @bhansa added example